# Trouble with Python move function: handling player starting outside the board

Tags: python, nested-lists

I'm working on a Python program where I have a move function that moves a player piece on a game board. The function should handle the case where the player starts outside the board, represented by a player position of (-1, -1). However, I'm having trouble getting it to work correctly

Here's the code for the move function:

```
import copy

def find_x(board, goal):
    row_index = -1
    col_index = -1

    for row in range(len(board)):
        for col in range(len(board[row])):
            if board[row][col] == goal:
                row_index = row
                col_index = col
                return (row_index, col_index)

    return (row_index, col_index)

def move(orig_board, curr_board, piece, direction):
    print("Entered move function")
    print("Direction:", direction)

    # Print curr_board to verify player piece representation
    print("Current Board:")
    for row in curr_board:
        print(row)

    if direction != "R" and direction != "D":
        print("Invalid direction:", direction)
        return (None, None)  # Invalid direction, return (None, None)

    # Find the player piece
    player_position = find_x(curr_board, piece)
    print("Player position:", player_position)
    if player_position == (-1, -1):
        print("Player piece not found")
        return (None, None)  # Player piece not found, return (None, None)

    curr_row, curr_col = player_position
    print("Current Position:", (curr_row, curr_col))

    if direction == "R":
        new_row = curr_row
        new_col = curr_col + 1

        # Adjust for moving to the next row if at the end of a row
        if new_col >= len(curr_board[curr_row]):
            new_row += 1
            new_col = 0

            # Check for out-of-bounds after adjusting
            if new_row >= len(curr_board):
                print("Out-of-bounds move")
                return (None, None)  # Out-of-bounds move, return (None, None)

    elif direction == "D":
        new_row = curr_row + 1
        new_col = curr_col

        # Check for out-of-bounds
        if new_row >= len(curr_board):
            print("Out-of-bounds move")
            return (None, None)  # Out-of-bounds move, return (None, None)

    print("New Position:", (new_row, new_col))

    # Store the room name before moving
    room_name = curr_board[new_row][new_col]

    # Perform the move
    new_board = copy.deepcopy(curr_board)  # Create a deepcopy of the current board to avoid modifying ORIG_BOARD
    new_board[curr_row][curr_col] = ""  # Update the previous position with an empty room
    new_board[new_row][new_col] = piece  # Move the player piece to the new position

    print("Updated Board:")
    for row in new_board:
        print(row)

    return (room_name, new_board)

# Example usage
orig_board = [['dining', 'living', 'garden'],
              ['lounge', 'game', 'gym'],
              ['spa', 'bedroom', 'office']]
curr_board = [['dining', 'living', 'garden'],
              ['lounge', 'game', 'gym'],
              ['spa', 'bedroom', 'office']]
piece = "X"
direction = "R"
result = move(orig_board, curr_board, piece, direction)
print("Result:", result)

move([['dining', 'living', 'garden'], ['lounge', 'game', 'gym'], ['spa', 'bedroom', 'office']],
     [['dining', 'living', 'garden'], ['lounge', 'game', 'gym'], ['spa', 'bedroom', 'office']],
     "X", "R")
```

This is what I wanted the output to be: ("dining",[["X","living","garden"],["lounge","game","gym"],["spa","bedroom","office"]])

Comment: Use `(0, -1)` as position outside of the board. Set `row_index = 0` in the first line of `find_x`.